# Is there a way of routing the audio stream (web-audio) node, as a virtual input stream source?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to build a voice-changer app using web-audio API.

```
    microphone.connect(dummyNode);
    dummyNode.connect(sourceAnalyserNode);
    sourceAnalyserNode.connect(processingNode);
    processingNode.connect(destinationAnalyserNode);   
    destinationAnalyserNode.connect(audioContext.destinationAnalyserNode);
```

I can hear the output which is processed, but I want to use this output audio-stream as and when the other sites are requesting for the microphone input (like building a web-extension). Any idea how it's possible?